# django populate model field from another model without ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working in App using exiting multiple databases (I can't modify them). I connect to all of them and can do queries and serializers without problem, but I want to populate a field form a Model into another Model where they have the same value:

```
class Cuisines(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cuisines'
        in_db = 'db_2'

class Companies(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ....
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cuisines'
        in_db = 'db_1'
        ...
```

view:

```
def cuisines(request): 
    companies = Companies.objects.all()
    for company in companies:
        result = Cuisines.objects.filter(company_id = company.id )
        serializer = OrderSerializer(result, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

the result looks:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Burger",company_id:"1" ...]
```

and I'm looking for:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Burger","company_id":"some name", }...]
```

UPDATE:
serializer

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Cuisines
        fields = ('id','name','company_id')
```

Comment: Update please your OrderSerializer code :)

Comment: The company_id field have REAL id of the Companies model table ?

Comment: exactly: Cuisines.company_id = Companies.id

Comment: Why are you not using models.ForeignKey ?

Comment: it is legacy database, I just connect to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to connect instances in view

```
def cuisines(request): 
    companies = Companies.objects.all()
    for company in companies:
        result = list(Cuisines.objects.filter(company_id=company.id))
        for o in result:
            setattr(o, 'company', company)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(result, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Serializer

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #eg. custom company_name field
    company_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='company.company_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Cuisines
        fields = ('id','name','company_name')
```

Comment: You can experiment with company_id = models.ForeignKey(Companies, on_delete=models.PROTECT), then manage.py makemigrations, then manage.py migrate --fake. I'm not sure how it will behaviour with multi db but if it will work you will get rly huge benefit which is native django ORM system.

Comment: well, I can't do any migration because I don't wont to add anything to the DBs :)

Comment: it works fine, and when there are more records in Companies table it returns only the first record : [{"id":1,"name":"Burger","company_id":"some name" }, {"id":2,"name":"test2","company_id":"some name", }....]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this in my latest project and I've created a dictionary where I put the values I wanted to return in it. So in your case:

```
result = []
for i in Cusiness.objects.all():
    d = {}
    company = Companies.objects.get(id = i.company_id)
    d["name"] = i.name
    d["company_id"] = company.name
    ...
    result.append(d)
```

Comment: where is the Companies object?